# How to use $or with the $lookup in mongodb query using go?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I want to get the data records from mongodb document using $or and $lookup.
Here is a query I make for assertion:-

```
pipeline1 := []bson.M{
    {"$lookup": bson.M{"from": "comment", "localField": "_id", "foreignField": "blog_id", "as": "comments"}},
    {"$addFields": bson.M{"comments": bson.M{"$size": "$comments"}}},
}
pipe1 := getCollection.Pipe(pipeline1)
```

In the above query it will first count the records and add the field with the particular data. But now I have a little change in the query is that now there are two more parameters i have to search with this using $or for regular expression I want that the function will doing the same thing but while getting the records if the user will entered any parameter then it will fetch the record by using that keyword and also make the count of that data.

**Edited**

I have to combined the above query with the below query:-

```
query["$or"] = []bson.M{
    bson.M{"title": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + value + ".*", "i"}},
    bson.M{"type": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + value + ".*", "i"}},
    bson.M{"author": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + value + ".*", "i"}},
    bson.M{"tags": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + value + ".*", "i"}},
}
```

I'm combining it like this but it return Nothing.

```
pipeline1 := []bson.M{
    {"$or": []bson.M{
        bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$in": ids}},
        bson.M{"type": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + types + ".*", "i"}},
        bson.M{"category": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + category + ".*", "i"}},
        bson.M{"author": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + keyword + ".*", "i"}},
        bson.M{"title": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + keyword + ".*", "i"}},
        bson.M{"tags": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + tag + ".*", "i"}}}},
    {"$lookup": bson.M{"from": "comment", "localField": "_id", "foreignField": "blog_id", "as": "comments"}},
    {"$addFields": bson.M{"comments": bson.M{"$size": "$comments"}}},
}
pipe1 := getCollection.Pipe(pipeline1)
```

**Latest Edit**

AS @kmdreko say I make a similar like that but does not works:-

```
 query := bson.M{}
query["$or"] = []bson.M{
    bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$in": ids}},
    bson.M{"type": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + types + ".*", "i"}},
    bson.M{"category": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + category + ".*", "i"}},
    bson.M{"author": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + keyword + ".*", "i"}},
    bson.M{"title": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + keyword + ".*", "i"}},
    bson.M{"tags": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + tag + ".*", "i"}},
}
fmt.Println(query)
pipeline1 := []bson.M{
    {"$lookup": bson.M{"from": "comment", "localField": "_id", "foreignField": "blog_id", "as": "comments"}},
    {"$addFields": bson.M{"comments": bson.M{"$size": "$comments"}}},
    {"$match": query},
}
fmt.Println(pipeline1)
pipe1 := getCollection.Pipe(pipeline1)
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're wanting, but mongodb has a [second $lookup form](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) (introduced in 3.6) that gives you more control over it by way of a sub-pipeline. That might be what you need...

Comment: @kmdreko see the edited question

Answer (score 0):

If the fields you're filtering are on the root document, then the first stage should be a `$match` stage. So the pipeline will look like this:

```
{ $match: { $or: [...] } }, // your query
{ $lookup: {...} },         // same as before
{ $addFields: {...} }       // same as before
```

Its surprising your query doesn't return an error as `$or` is not an [aggregation pipeline stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries).

Comment: I make a query like you said but it does not works.Why?

Comment: `$match` should be the first stage (but it wouldn't affect results) in this case. What do you mean by doesn't work? Could you supply some sample data to make sure I've made the right suggestions?